# Average Constant In SQL Query

Tags: sql

I have a database used for a store.
I have a table with different items and their prices.
I need to get the name and price of each item whose price is greater than the average price of all items, but I also need to get that average value in the same query.

I can easily get the name and price of those items like this:

```
select art_name, art_price
from articles
where art_price>(select avg(art_price) from articles);
```

But I don't know how to get the average value in the same query.

What happens to you to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `having`

```
select art_name, art_price
from articles
having art_price>avg(art_price);
```

**EDIT** after comment:

```
select art_name, art_price, avg(art_price) as average
from articles
group by art_name, art_price;
```

Comment: I need to get the avg in the same query. Each line must show the name, the price and the avg(all prices).

Comment: just add it in the select.

Comment: It doesn't work. I t shows this error 00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"

Comment: I edited my answer, add a `group by`. Have a look at [ORA-00937](https://www.tekstream.com/resource-center/ora-00937-not-a-single-group-function/). Also please specify your RDBMS next time.